# PHP updating a multidimensional array by providing a smaller array, overwrite keys that exist, but retain other data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Sorry long question. It will be clearer here what I actually want to do.

Please consider this relatively simple multidimensional array

```
'domain1.com' => 
    array (size=9)
        'serverip' => null
        'dedicatedip' => null
        'username' => null
        'password' => null
        'web_template' => null
        'datacenter' => null
        'unix_time_start' => null
        'is_trial' => null
        'billing' => 
            array (size=2)
                'upgrade' => boolean false
                'vip' => boolean true
'domain2.com' => 
    array (size=9)
        'serverip' => null
        'dedicatedip' => null
        'username' => null
        'password' => null
        'web_template' => null
        'datacenter' => null
        'unix_time_start' => null
        'is_trial' => null
        'billing' => 
            array (size=2)
                'upgrade' => boolean false
                'vip' => boolean true
```

Note that the first level keys are domain names, and the last value 'billing' is also an array.

I can update bits of information by using array_merge using this simplified function.

```
function update_domain_details( $domain, $array ) {
    $large = array( ... ) // as above
    $current_large = $large[$domain];
    $large[$domain] = array_merge($current_large, $array );
}

$array = array(
    is_trial => true,
);

update_domain_details('domain1.com', $array );
```

But the problem I am having is when I try to update anything in the billing sub-array. For eg;

```
$array = array(
    'billing' => array('upgrade' => true),
);
```

This would overwrite the entire billing sub-array and I would lose the 'vip' values.

I have looked into array_merge_recursive but it is just getting a little confusing for me.

I want to be able to pass an array into a function along with the domain name and it will overlay that array on top of the larger one without loosing any information. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog post on [array_merge_recursive vs array_replace_recursive](http://jontai.me/blog/2011/12/array_merge_recursive-vs-array_replace_recursive/)

Simply substituting **array_merge** with **array_replace_recursive** appears to has fixed the issue for me.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php